# data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on null values - if statement hasn't worked

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to run this code in VB.net

```
SQL = "SELECT SUM(amount) FROM billing_payments WHERE invoice_sequence = '" & reader.GetString(0) & "';"
            myCommand2.Connection = conn2
            myCommand2.CommandText = SQL
            reader2 = myCommand2.ExecuteReader
            If reader2.Read Then
                If Not IsDBNull(reader2.GetString(0)) Then
                    account_balance = (account_balance - reader2.GetString(0))
                End If
            End If
            reader2.Close()
```

Which works fine if there is data returned but when there is no data, I get an error message saying:

data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on null values

I have tried adding in the IF statement to check if the data is NULL but that hasn't worked.

Have I added this in incorrectly?

Comment: The problem is what null means in different contexts. IsDBNull() is used to check if a field is null. I.E. if a row is returned, but a particular column of that row is null. But in order for .net to check that, there has to be a row returned in the first place. If your sql does not return any row at all, then there is nothing to .Read, and therefore the IsDBNull function does not have a field to check if it's null

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. What can I do with this one then?

Comment: Personally, I usually start those kinds of blocks with "If myReader IsNot Nothing AndAlso myReader.Read() Then"

Comment: You should turn on Option Strict to avoid other type conversion issues: `account_balance = (account_balance - reader2.GetString(0))` cant make any sense. Subtracting a string from a value makes no sense

Comment: First of all... this is vulnerable to what we call a 2nd order sql injection attack. **NEVER** use string concatenation to put data in an sql command. Use parameterized queries instead. Second... it really likes you  should be able to fold this query into the parent query, rather than looping through a data reader. That will likely be an order of magnitude more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If reader2 <> Nothing Then
    If reader2.Read Then
        If Not reader2.IsDBNull(0) Then
        '...
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Does a check on nothing work, like this?

```
If reader2.GetString(0) IsNot Nothing Then
   account_balance = (account_balance - reader2.GetString(0))
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

"IsDBNull" which is (DBNull.Value) indicates a value that is missing.

**It is not equivalent to "null" or to "String.Empty".**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.isdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx

So first check for NULL or Nothing. Then check for non existence.

```
If reader2.GetString(0) IsNot Nothing And  Not IsDBNull(reader2.GetString(0)) Then
  ''''''''''''
  '''''''''''''''
End If
```